# How to read bz2 file as an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

There is a function you may know gzfile which "Read entire gz-file into an array", how can you do the same with bz2? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you trying to read the decompressed contents into an array? Or the compressed file itself (in which case you'd use standard I/O)? Do you need to do the decompression in PHP, in which case you'd need to find/write the bz2 algorithm, or can you use a library or command-line tools?

Comment: Yes i am trying to decompress contents into array, just like gzfile function, but for bz2 files, doesn't matter how just need some ideas, thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in function.

You could do something like this (add some sanity checks, etc):

```
function bzfile($filename){
    $p = popen('bunzip2 -c ' . $filename, 'r');
    $a = array();
    while($a[] = fgets($p);
    return $a;
}
```

This assumes a unix-like os with a bunzip2 binary installed.  It runs buznip2 on your file.  The -c option means "send uncompressed data to stdout instead of affecting the file on disk).  That output behaves like a file handle, so you can fgets on it to read lines.

EDIT:  There is [an extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bzip2.php) that provides some built-in bz2 functionality, though sadly, no bzfile().  If the bzip2 extension is available in your environment, you could rewrite the above like:

```
function bzfile($file){
    $fp = bzopen('foo.bz2','r');
    $a = array();
    while ($a[] = fgets($fp));
    return $a;
}
```

This will not require a unix environment or installed bunzip2 binary.

(NOTE: this all assumes the bzipped file is text and doesn't contain binary data, since you wanted a replacement for file())

Comment: I does contain binary data i get Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given i gues i need to extract contents first and then run your function